# How to get time difference between current date time and timestamp value in HH:MM:SS

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, timer

What i want is simple, i have timestamp in my mysql database that records date and time data registers. What i want is to calculate the timediff between timestamp and current time then subtract from 3hours to know time remaining in hh:mm:ss format, please someone help out.

Comment: I think you're asking how to calculate the time remaining in a 3 hour period starting at a datetime stored in a DB, to be displayed in HH:MM:SS format... if so see my answer below, if not please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following part in your query:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), column_with_date_to_compare))), '%H:%i')
```

You must skip the AVG part if you do not want averages but a result per row (or you have only one row to check) (or use GROUP BY [something])

The part 'then subtract from 3hours', I don't understand. You only want to show the records where the time is less than 3 hours? Just use WHERE TIME(record_to_check) > (NOW() - 10800).

If you want to add, calculate or do other things to influence the result, just do so before SEC_TO_TIME, you can do the math (with seconds) there.

Comment: thanks, yes i want to show the record time less than 3hours. so hw do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've interpretted your question as how to calculate the time remaining in a 3 hour period starting at a datetime stored in a DB, to be displayed in HH:MM:SS format...
I generally find it easier to manipulate dates / times in php rather than wihtin an SQL query. So my approach would be to:

- read strings from the database
- convert them into unix timestamps (ie
  number of seconds elapsed since a given epoch)
- manipulate them mathematically (ie add on 3 hours and subtract the curent time)
- lastly convert the result back into a date / time in your chosen
  format.

Assuming $start_str has been read from your DB

```
$start_str = '08-03-2017 11:10:00';
$start_ts = strtotime("$start_str");
$end_ts = $start_ts + (3 * 60 * 60);
$now_ts = strtotime('NOW');
$remaining_ts = $end_ts - $now_ts;
$remaining_str = ($remaining_ts > 0)? sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', ($remaining_ts/3600),($remaining_ts/60%60), $remaining_ts%60) : "None, time's up";

echo ($start_str.'|'.$start_ts.'|'.$end_ts.'|'.$now_ts.'|'.$remaining_ts.'|'.$remaining_str);
```

Examples...
08-03-2017 11:10:00|1488971400|1488982200|1488983863|-1663|**None, time's up**
08-03-2017 14:30:00|1488983400|1488994200|1488983982|10218|**02:50:18**

Obviously in reality you're only interested in the last field, but the others show you what you're playing with during the process.

Comment: so how can i make this functiona?

Comment: How do i make this $start_str = '08-03-2017 11:10:00'; get time from my database timestamp

Comment: The code in my answer was conceptual, to give you an idea how to manipulate the timestamp. You would need to include other PHP code to actually read the timestamp value from your database, that would involve a more intimate knowledge of your database structure etc.

Comment: Okay i managed to get it to read data from my database timestamp, however the Output still shows the calculated rows. Please how do i only display the Time Remaining only in this formate HH:MM:SS only... Please help!!

Comment: Thanks Alot,I got It!! Very Grateful for your assistance